# Move Developer Folder

Tags: development, folders

I want to free some space on my SSD.

Is there a way to move the Developer folder from my root drive to another one without breaking anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not hurt anything, or it might. A better (if more time-consuming) solution might be to delete your existing Developer folder, then re-install the dev tools to the drive you want them to be on. This will ensure that everything that has to be in `/Developer` is there.

Answer (score 3):

Some files in the /Developer path are referenced when you launch specific functions within  Xcode. If you need to recover space and absolutely has to move /Developer, you could try

- Move the /Developer folder to the alternate path and symlink it so
  that Xcode still finds it at /. Note: I haven't tried it with Xcode 4.x, so please share if this works.
- alternative is to do a clean uninstall using 'sudo
  /Library/uninstall-devtools' and custom reinstall Xcode by
  specifying a different path.

Comment: Using a symlink appears to work fine -- I just did it, browsed several topics, etc.